# How to populate configuration files over a lot of servers?

Tags: server, ssh, configuration, home-directory

I have configuration files at my home directory (.bashrc, .gitignore, etc.). When I find something helpful for me I add this information into this files. But also I have access via ssh to different servers, where I'm also using cli and need this changes.

What I'm doing now? Connecting via ssh and change everything manually.

What I want to achieve? I want to do it automatically.

How I can make it? What you can recommend for me?

Comment: If you need to sync the same files occasionally, the simplest thing is to use `rsync` in a script. You can run it with `cron` as well.

Comment: Have a look at puppet. It does this and more ;) https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/puppet.html

Comment: You might also consider a git repo of your dotfiles, a lot of people prefer it

Answer (score 0):

A good way is managing your configuration files in a code repository, saying github.

Every time you change locally, push your change. And in other servers, you just need to pull the changes down.

A lot of people host their dotfiles in github. You can take a look [github dotfiles](http://dotfiles.github.io/).